# how to map url id to a content on server?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, servlets

i have a unique id for each product .how To display a product without a separate html for each product?

I like to display them like pinterest.

eg
url: /product/12345

when user clicks on /product/12345 it should render the content.

what are the options i have to generate content in that fashion

http://www.pinterest.com/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are using on the server, such as ASP.Net MVC, Ruby On Rails, PHP, etc. Your tags don't include any server-side language so I assume you're trying to do this only in JavaScript. This creates an issue if a user wants to bookmark the URL. Without a separate page for that URL, if they try to navigate to that page from outside the site, they will get a 404 error. It is better that you use handle this using server programming instead, or look into URL forwarding on the server.

The usual way in JavaScript is using an Ajax call to replace the element with content from another html file on the server. Best to use jQuery for that:

```
$( "#divIdToReplace" ).load( "path/to/content.html" );
```

And to have the URL change, you'll use HTML5's pushState:

```
history.pushState(stateObj, "product 12345", "12345.html");
```

Note that 12345.html doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I am using Java ee. servlets. I have flexibility to choose any java based framework on the server side.

Comment: Then you should ask how to achieve this in Java and include the Java tag.

Answer (score 0):

While showing the products on the page you should embed link something like -

<a href="{contextPath}/product?id=1234">Details</a>

so once you click on the link you will be redirected to path www.yourwebsite.com/product?id=1234 , where product is your servlet.

Now in the servlet you can get this id from request parameter as  request.getParameter("id");

now get the details of the product from the db.

ProductDAO.getProductByID(id);

and then set it in the request attribute using

request.setAttribute("Product",product);

now redirect to the page your you want to show the details of the Product assume details.jsp

and then there get product from request attribute as

request.getAttribute("product");

and here you get what you wanted.